# ffmpeg doesn't record RTSP stream

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm trying to record RTSP stream from Dahua IP camera which is located on 10.10.10.10 (for example purpose), on Windows it works well and on previous ubuntu version I had (18) it was also working well. However on Ubuntu Server 22.04 it runs but ends without any error.

`ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.10.10:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1"&"subtype=1 -movflags +frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4`

And debug output of the ffmpeg is:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
[...]
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.10.10:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1.
[tcp @ 0x55c812986800] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x55c812986800] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x55c812986800] Address 10.10.10.10 port 554
[tcp @ 0x55c812986800] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x55c812986800] Address 10.10.10.10 port 554
[tcp @ 0x55c812986800] Starting connection attempt to 10.10.10.10 port 554
[tcp @ 0x55c812986800] Successfully connected to 10.10.10.10 port 554
[rtsp @ 0x55c812983740] SDP:
v=0
o=- 2252669512 2252669512 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=Media Server
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=control:*
a=packetization-supported:DH
a=rtppayload-supported:DH
a=range:npt=now-
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 98
a=control:trackID=0
a=framerate:25.000000
a=rtpmap:98 H265/90000
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=1;sprop-sps=QgEBAUAAAAMAAAMAAAMAAAMAmaAFggCQf5a7kbBrlUE=;sprop-pps=RAHAc8BMkA==;sprop-vps=QAEMAf//AUAAAAMAAAMAAAMAAAMAmawJ
a=recvonly

[rtsp @ 0x55c812983740] video codec set to: hevc
[rtp @ 0x55c8129899c0] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x55c81298a480] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x55c81298a480] end receive buffer size reported is 425984
[udp @ 0x55c812989e00] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x55c812989e00] end receive buffer size reported is 425984
[rtsp @ 0x55c812983740] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[rtsp @ 0x55c812983740] hello state=0
Failed to parse interval end specification ''
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] nal_unit_type: 32(VPS), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] nal_unit_type: 33(SPS), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] nal_unit_type: 34(PPS), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Decoding VPS
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Main profile bitstream
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Decoding SPS
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Main profile bitstream
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Decoding PPS
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] nal_unit_type: 32(VPS), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] nal_unit_type: 33(SPS), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] nal_unit_type: 34(PPS), nuh_layer_id: 0, temporal_id: 0
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Decoding VPS
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Main profile bitstream
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Decoding SPS
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Main profile bitstream
[hevc @ 0x55c812989100] Decoding PPS
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.10.10:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: hevc (Main), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(tv, left), 704x576, 0/1, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url out.mp4.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: out.mp4.
File '123.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
[file @ 0x55c8129ba9c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
[mp4 @ 0x55c8129bb800] Empty MOOV enabled; disabling automatic bitstream filtering
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: hevc (Main), 1 reference frame (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, left), 704x576 (0x0), 0/1, q=2-31, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
No more output streams to write to, finishing.e=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.10.10:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 0 packets read (0 bytes);
  Total: 0 packets (0 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (123.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 0 packets muxed (0 bytes);
  Total: 0 packets (0 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
```

Comment: try to use a single quotation mark to delimitate the url , like this `'rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.10.10:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1"&"subtype=1'`

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I tried and it ends without recording anything, same as before. On ubuntu 18.04 it worked but I dont remember what ffmpeg version it was.

Comment: Try to leave out the audio stuff `-acodec copy`, you don't have audio anyways

Comment: What I get right now is `[rtsp @ 0x55ac5ab4b740] method OPTIONS failed: 401 Unauthorized
rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.0.10:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1: Server returned 401 Unauthorized (authorization failed)`